# How did I break scrolling on this page?

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of building a single page scrolling website with a fixed navigation bar at the top. This is also going to be a responsive site. The columns seem to stack just fine at the break point. But somehow after I made the header fixed I broke the scroll capability. There is text below what the user can see on the screen, so a scroll bar should appear. I even tried putting the main content in a container outside of the responsive grid and giving the container a height of 2000 px, but I scrapped that idea because it had no effect. So, hopefully someone can tell me what I broke.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title Here</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simplegrid.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
</head>

<body>

<! --- navigation --- >

<div class="nav-cont">
  <div class="navigation">
              <div class="grid">
                <div class="col-4-12">
                  <img src="sblogo.png"alt="logo" height="84" width="88">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2-12">
                  <a href="#">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2-12">
                  <a href="#">About</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2-12">
                  <a href="#">Pricing</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2-12">
                  <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>

  </div>
</div>          

<! ---Main Content --- >

<div class="intro">
  <div class="grid grid-pad">
    <div class="col-1-1">
      <h1>Big Heading</h1>
      <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="about">
  <div class="grid grid-pad">
    <div class="col-1-1">
      <h1>Section Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lacus a dolor faucibus gravida. Pellentesque urna metus, varius consectetur sagittis eu, imperdiet nec neque. In dictum accumsan auctor. Maecenas non odio elit. Donec quis urna vitae nisi egestas porta. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed elementum, nunc ut sollicitudin placerat, est enim molestie sem, eu tempor magna leo eu eros. In fringilla dolor quis lacinia lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque nec est placerat, molestie ante quis, sollicitudin magna. </p><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lacus a dolor faucibus gravida. Pellentesque urna metus, varius consectetur sagittis eu, imperdiet nec neque. In dictum accumsan auctor. Maecenas non odio elit. Donec quis urna vitae nisi egestas porta. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed elementum, nunc ut sollicitudin placerat, est enim molestie sem, eu tempor magna leo eu eros. In fringilla dolor quis lacinia lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque nec est placerat, molestie ante quis, sollicitudin magna. </p><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lacus a dolor faucibus gravida. Pellentesque urna metus, varius consectetur sagittis eu, imperdiet nec neque. In dictum accumsan auctor. Maecenas non odio elit. Donec quis urna vitae nisi egestas porta. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed elementum, nunc ut sollicitudin placerat, est enim molestie sem, eu tempor magna leo eu eros. In fringilla dolor quis lacinia lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque nec est placerat, molestie ante quis, sollicitudin magna. </p><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lacus a dolor faucibus gravida. Pellentesque urna metus, varius consectetur sagittis eu, imperdiet nec neque. In dictum accumsan auctor. Maecenas non odio elit. Donec quis urna vitae nisi egestas porta. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed elementum, nunc ut sollicitudin placerat, est enim molestie sem, eu tempor magna leo eu eros. In fringilla dolor quis lacinia lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque nec est placerat, molestie ante quis, sollicitudin magna. </p><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lacus a dolor faucibus gravida. Pellentesque urna metus, varius consectetur sagittis eu, imperdiet nec neque. In dictum accumsan auctor. Maecenas non odio elit. Donec quis urna vitae nisi egestas porta. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed elementum, nunc ut sollicitudin placerat, est enim molestie sem, eu tempor magna leo eu eros. In fringilla dolor quis lacinia lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque nec est placerat, molestie ante quis, sollicitudin magna. </p><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This stylesheet provides the grid:

```
/*
  Simple Grid
  Learn More - http://dallasbass.com/simple-grid-a-lightweight-responsive-css-grid/
  Project Page - http://thisisdallas.github.com/Simple-Grid/
  Author - Dallas Bass
  Site - dallasbass.com
*/

*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px; /* column-space */
}

.grid {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 755px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.grid-pad {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px; /* grid-space to left */
    padding-right: 0px; /* grid-space to right: (grid-space-left - column-space) e.g. 20px-20px=0 */
}

.push-right {
    float: right;
}

/* Content Columns */

.col-1-1 {
    width: 100%;
}
.col-2-3, .col-8-12 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-2, .col-6-12 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-1-3, .col-4-12 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-1-4, .col-3-12 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-1-5 {
    width: 20%;
}

.col-1-6, .col-2-12 {
    width: 16.667%;
}

.col-1-7 {
    width: 14.28%;
}

.col-1-8 {
    width: 12.5%;
}

.col-1-9 {
    width: 11.1%;
}

.col-1-10 {
    width: 10%;
}

.col-1-11 {
    width: 9.09%;
}

.col-1-12 {
    width: 8.33%
}

/* Layout Columns */

.col-11-12 {
    width: 91.66%
}

.col-10-12 {
    width: 83.333%;
}

.col-9-12 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-5-12 {
    width: 41.66%;
}

.col-7-12 {
    width: 58.33%
}



/* Pushing blocks */

.push-2-3, .push-8-12 {
    margin-left: 66.66%;
}

.push-1-2, .push-6-12 {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.push-1-3, .push-4-12 {
    margin-left: 33.33%;
}

.push-1-4, .push-3-12 {
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.push-1-5 {
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.push-1-6, .push-2-12 {
    margin-left: 16.667%;
}

.push-1-7 {
    margin-left: 14.28%;
}

.push-1-8 {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
}

.push-1-9 {
    margin-left: 11.1%;
}

.push-1-10 {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.push-1-11 {
    margin-left: 9.09%;
}

.push-1-12 {
    margin-left: 8.33%
}


@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .grid {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 0;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 20px; /* grid-space to left */
        padding-right: 10px; /* grid-space to right: (grid-space-left - column-space) e.g. 20px-10px=10px */
    }

    [class*='col-'] {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 10px; /* column-space */
    }


    /* Mobile Layout */

    [class*='mobile-col-'] {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 10px; /* column-space */
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mobile-col-2-3, .mobile-col-8-12 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-2, .mobile-col-6-12 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-3, .mobile-col-4-12 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-4, .mobile-col-3-12 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-5 {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-6, .mobile-col-2-12 {
        width: 16.667%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-7 {
        width: 14.28%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-8 {
        width: 12.5%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-9 {
        width: 11.1%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-10 {
        width: 10%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-11 {
        width: 9.09%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-12 {
        width: 8.33%
    }

    /* Layout Columns */

    .mobile-col-11-12 {
        width: 91.66%
    }

    .mobile-col-10-12 {
        width: 83.333%;
    }

    .mobile-col-9-12 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .mobile-col-5-12 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }

    .mobile-col-7-12 {
        width: 58.33%
    }

    .hide-on-mobile {
        display: none !important;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
```

And this is my custom stylesheet for everything else:

```
body {

}

.nav-cont {
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
 position: fixed;  
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
}

.navigation {

}



.navigation .grid {

}

.navigation .grid .col-2-12 {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient( black, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) );
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;

}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}



.intro {

}

.about {

}

}
```

I'm sure this is something simple I've missed, but I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrapped all of your content in the fixed `div` with class `nav-cont`, it was removed from the document flow. What you want to do instead is make only your header image fixed, then add a spacer element (another `col-4-12`) that takes its place in the document flow.

The relevant CSS I added:

```
.navigation .grid > *:first-child {
    position: fixed;
}
.navigation .grid > *:first-child, .navigation .grid > .spacer {
    height: 84px;
}
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="col-4-12">
    <img src="sblogo.png" alt="logo" height="84" width="88">
</div>
<div class="col-4-12 spacer">
</div>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle (reduce the width to get the mobile view): https://jsfiddle.net/tfypuymg/1/

Comment: I see where your going. I was actually trying to give the entire header a fixed position. My attempts to accomplish that up to this point have broken the responsive features of the page. Specifically, causing the header to cover up the top of the page. I want the navigation to stay in place as the user scrolls, and also adjust its size to fit various screens. If I'm taking the wrong approach, I'm open to suggestions.